# Purple screen with diagonal lines when starting Windows

Tags: multi-boot, windows

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 laptop.

This screen shows up for 5-10 seconds when starting Windows.

[image]

There is no problem after this, everything runs fine.

Comment: Seems like a graphics driver issue to me. Has it been there since the beginning?

Comment: @AzkerM I bought the laptop about a week back, and it has been there since the beginning. The graphics card is a 920MX which had outdated drivers but the problem is still there even after updating it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into Ubuntu by selecting it from the GRUB menu (GRUB menu screenshot in step 4).
2. Open the terminal and run `sudo fdisk -l`
3. Restart your system with `sudo reboot`
4. After loading you will be asked to select a boot option. Select Windows 10 from the GRUB menu.

   [image]
5. It may boot into safe mode.
6. In Windows 10 Start menu type *System Configuration* -> select *Boot* tab -> uncheck *Safe boot* -> click *Apply* button -> click *OK* button.

   [image]
7. Reboot again with `sudo reboot`.